# How do I set latex face attributes in init.el?

Tags: auctex, faces

When I try to put

```
 (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-italic-face nil :foreground green)
 (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-math-face nil :foreground orange)
 (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-script-char-face nil :foreground red)
 (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-string-face nil :foreground red)
```

into my init.el (green & are variables I have given values), I am told that
'font-latex-... are 'invalid faces'.  this also happens if i try to evaluate
the expressions before having opened a latex buffer.  how am i suppsed to
customize these faces in my init.el?  (i don't want to use custom-set-faces.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard method to do this sort of thing, given that the faces are defined in the `font-latex` library:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'font-latex
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-italic-face nil :foreground green)
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-math-face nil :foreground orange)
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-script-char-face nil :foreground red)
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-string-face nil :foreground red))
```

This way, you don't force the loading of `font-latex` before you need it. If the file has already been loaded, the commands will be run immediately; otherwise, they will be run after the file is loaded, as the name indicates. (Strictly speaking, they will be run after the loading of any file that runs `(provide 'font-latex)`. But no other file should do that.)

Comment: Do you mean `with-eval-after-load`?  Your example will not work as `eval-after-load` expects `FORM` as argument and needs a quoted `'(progn ...)` for multiple forms.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Indeed, I was a bit quick there. Thanks; edited. Looking at my own init file, I see that I made my own equivalent of the `with-eval-after-load` macro once, probably before that macro made it into the emacs source. I use both my home brewed macro and the official one – time to go clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load or autoload a symbol before you can customize it. The easiest way is to insert

```
(require 'font-latex)
```

before the `set-face-attribute` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with `ediff`. The faces are defined [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.2/lisp/vc/ediff-init.el#L807-L1167), required [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.2/lisp/vc/ediff.el#L112), but they're loaded only when I start resolving a conflict. But there's a [`ediff-load-hook`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.2/lisp/vc/ediff.el#L1652) in `ediff.el`, so I did this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ediff-load-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-face-attribute 'ediff-even-diff-A nil :background "dim grey")
            (set-face-attribute 'ediff-odd-diff-A nil :background "dim grey")
            (set-face-attribute 'ediff-even-diff-B nil :background "dim grey")
            (set-face-attribute 'ediff-odd-diff-B nil :background "dim grey")
            (set-face-attribute 'ediff-even-diff-C nil :background "dim grey")
            (set-face-attribute 'ediff-odd-diff-C nil :background "dim grey")))
```